# SQL Multiple inner joins with max() for latest recorded entry

Tags: sql, max, inner-join, winsql

Attempting to build SQL with INNER JOIN's. The INNER JOIN's work ok, now I need to add the MAX() function for limiting the rows to just most recent. Added this INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_record ON SELECT cr.PATID, cr.date_of_diagnosis, cr.most_recent_diagnosis...
Received this SQL code error, need some help, I'm sure it a simple oversight but my eyes are getting dim from looking so long...

Syntax error: [SQLCODE: <-4>:

```
SQLCODE: <-4>:<A term expected, beginning with one of the following: identifier, constant, aggregate, %ALPHAUP, %EXACT, %MVR, %SQLSTRING, %

[%msg: < The SELECT list of the subquery


SELECT pd.patient_name,
       cr.PATID,
       cr.date_of_diagnosis,
       cr.EPISODE_NUMBER,
       ce.diagnosing_clinician_value, 
       ce.data_entry_user_name,
       most_recent_diagnosis
FROM client_diagnosis_record cr 
INNER JOIN patient_current_demographics pd ON cr.patid = pd.patid 
INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_entry ce ON ce.patid = pd.patid
                                    AND cr.ID = ce.DiagnosisRecord
INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_record ON (SELECT cr.PATID,
                                              cr.date_of_diagnosis,
                                              cr.most_recent_diagnosis
                                       FROM ( SELECT patid,
                                                     date_of_diagnosis,
                                                     MAX(ID) AS most_recent_diagnosis
                                              FROM client_diagnosis_record) cr
 INNER JOIN RADplus_users ru ON ru.staff_member_id = ce.diagnosing_clinician_code
 WHERE cr.PATID <> '1'
 AND ce.diagnosis_status_value ='Active'
 AND (ru.user_description LIKE '%SOA' OR ru.user_description LIKE '%OA')
 GROUP BY cr.PATID
```

Comment: The code in your question is incorrectly formatted

Comment: can you help with the correct code format, point the details out so I can fix it

Comment: Is the incorrect format pertain to the? INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_record ON (
   SELECT cr.PATID, cr.date_of_diagnosis, cr.most_recent_diagnosis
   FROM ( SELECT patid, date_of_diagnosis, MAX(ID) AS most_recent_diagnosis 
   )

Comment: Dont you see the FROM client_diagnosis_record )   at the end of your code block?

Comment: Looks like I'm missing one of the )'s

Comment: INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_record ON (
   SELECT cr.PATID, cr.date_of_diagnosis, cr.most_recent_diagnosis
   FROM ( SELECT patid, date_of_diagnosis, MAX(ID) AS most_recent_diagnosis FROM client_diagnosis_record ) cr
   )

Comment: You can try editing your question so that it looks readable

Comment: What's the database? Sybase, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post.

Comment: the database is Cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to re-format you query and it seems your query syntax is not correct. You may try below query -

```
SELECT pd.patient_name,
       cr.PATID,
       cr.date_of_diagnosis,
       cr.EPISODE_NUMBER,
       ce.diagnosing_clinician_value, 
       ce.data_entry_user_name,
       most_recent_diagnosis
FROM client_diagnosis_record cr
INNER JOIN (SELECT patid,
                   date_of_diagnosis,
                   MAX(ID) AS most_recent_diagnosis
            FROM client_diagnosis_record
            GROUP BY patid,
                     date_of_diagnosis) cr2 ON cr.PATID = cr2.PATID
                                            AND cr.date_of_diagnosis = cr2.date_of_diagnosis
                                            AND cr.ID = cr2.most_recent_diagnosis
INNER JOIN patient_current_demographics pd ON cr.patid = pd.patid 
INNER JOIN client_diagnosis_entry ce ON ce.patid = pd.patid
                                    AND cr.ID = ce.DiagnosisRecord
INNER JOIN RADplus_users ru ON ru.staff_member_id = ce.diagnosing_clinician_code
WHERE cr.PATID <> '1'
AND ce.diagnosis_status_value ='Active'
AND (ru.user_description LIKE '%SOA' OR ru.user_description LIKE '%OA')
GROUP BY cr.PATID
```

Comment: thanks, that really helped, I was out sick for the past 4 days